# Using the serial port

Tags: vb.net

For some time I've been working on learning how to program VB.NET. With the help of this page and the internet, I managed to create a program that sends some hex values to an interface box and get a routine response from it.

The problem here is that the communication was TCP/IP. But now I have a new box with a USB interface and now I do not have the slightest idea of how to send and receive those same hex values using the Serial port.

Below is the code. I don't know if someone could help me set it up for a serial port named COM13 or at least explain to me what to do.

This is what the program does.

1. Push scan
2. Connects to the TCP/IP of the BOX (10.2.12.65)
3. Sends the activation protocol E1 33
4. Sends the get date command  05 6c 29 f1 3c 81
5. Box responds back date with bytes
6. When the program reads the byte corresponding to 81(hex) it starts converting them into characters and adding them to a string to be displayed on the textbox on the bottom.

That's basically it. The problem is that until now I have been able to send only text strings but the box does not recognize it and it responds garbage and not the date.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets  
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO  

Public  Class Form1
    Dim client As New TcpClient
    Dim transmit As NetworkStream
    Dim protocol As Byte()
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim ByteArrayToHexStr As String = String.Empty
    Dim message As String
    Dim datos_byte As Byte()
    Dim respuesta As [String] = [String].Empty
    Dim transision As [String] = [String].Empty
    Dim Date_full As [String] = [String].Empty

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Clear()
        client = New TcpClient("10.2.12.65", 10001)
        transmit = client.GetStream()
        protocol = {225, 51} ' E1 33 in hex value
        transmit.Write(protocol, 0, protocol.Length)
        Thread.Sleep(45)

        data = {5, 108, 41, 241, 60, 129} ' 05 6c 29 f1 3c 81 in hex value
        transmit.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        data = New Byte(66) {}
        Thread.Sleep(45)

        Dim bytes As Int32 = transmit.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        Dim Date1 As String = String.Empty
        Dim Date2 As String = String.Empty
        Dim Date_temp As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(data)
            Date1 = data(i)
            If Date1 = "129" Then
                Date_temp = i + 1
                i = 1000
                For k As Integer = 0 To 5
                    If k = 0 Then
                        Date1 = data(Date_temp + k)
                        Date_full = Chr(Date1)
                    Else
                        Date1 = data(Date_temp + k)
                        Date2 = Chr(Date1)
                        Date_full = Date_full & Date2
                    End If
                Next
            Else
            End If
        Next
        Thread.Sleep(45)

        transmit.Close()
        client.Close()
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Date_full
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just like you declared a new TcpClient you'd declare a Ports.SerialPort object instead (given your current Imports statements). Then you'd set the properties for the port (name, baud, etc). Then Open it. Use the Write method. Close it. Then handle the port's DataReceived event to buffer the response and act accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much, you were right, it's the same as the tcp, i just needed to configure the port.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Microsoft's example of the SerialPort class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

If you get garbage back that might indicate the baudrate is configured incorrectly. I'm not sure what you mean by 'box' but this device should have a specified baudrate which you should be able to find in its datasheet or product information.